# LWJGL: How to tell if Mouse is in bounds of complex shape?

Tags: java, game-engine, lwjgl

I have a complex oval on my custom OpenGL Display which needs to modify it's state when the mouse enters its bounds(the ortho perspective never changes as this is a 2D game). My oval is created using :

```
public class RenderOval {
public static double r = 0.2;
public static double g = 0.3;
public static double b = 0.5;
public static void renderOval(double locX, double locY, double width, double height){
    GL11.glPushMatrix();

    //Set Drawing Color - Will Remain this color until otherwise specified
    GL11.glColor3d(r,g,b);  

    //Draw Circle
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_POLYGON);
        //Change the 6 to 12 to increase the steps (number of drawn points) for a smoother circle
        //Note that anything above 24 will have little affect on the circles appearance
        //Play with the numbers till you find the result you are looking for
        //Value 1.5 - Draws Triangle
        //Value 2 - Draws Square
        //Value 3 - Draws Hexagon
        //Value 4 - Draws Octagon
        //Value 5 - Draws Decagon
        //Notice the correlation between the value and the number of sides
        //The number of sides is always twice the value given this range
        for(double i = 0; i < 2 * Math.PI; i += Math.PI / 24) //<-- Change this Value
                GL11.glVertex3d(Math.cos(i) * width+locX, Math.sin(i) * height+locY, 0.0);

    GL11.glEnd();
    //Draw Circle
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}
}
```

This Is a very complex shape with many vertices. But for a regular square I would know how to check if the mouse is in the bounds of the box:

```
if((Mouse.getX<(box.startX+box.width))&&((Mouse.getX>(box.startX)))){
mouse.isInXBounds = true;
}
```

However I am at a complete loss of how to check this against any custom made shapes. Any help would be vastly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/76463) answer describes how to check whether a point is inside an ellipse (oval). It won't help with shapes containing fewer sides, but it can hopefully give you a place to start.